# Creating Hovmoller Diagram in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, diagram

Hovmoller diagrams are useful in indicating changes through time in specific locations. I usually create this in GrADS but I am wondering if it is also possible to create Hovmoller Diagram in ArcGIS 10.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Since this is more a statistical chart than spatial display of data, I'm not sure there is a way. A quick search turned up little information, but I did find [an exchange](https://lists.nicholas.duke.edu/sympa/arc/mget-help/2010-07/msg00001.html) where someone apparently familiar with such diagrams said they didn't know of a way and usually used R or MATLAB to create them.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. Exactly as I suspected, it couldn't be done or at least nobody has done this yet on ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are proficient in python, I suggest creating one using the **[matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)** module. Though, it looks like you may need to install **[Iris](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/v1.0/examples/graphics/hovmoller.html?highlight=hovmoller)** first.

Alternatively, it looks like someone has written a tool for this. See [**this Github repository**](https://github.com/ahaberlie/hovmoller).